# TextRank Algorithm Space and Time Complexity

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, big-o, space-complexity

I am trying to determine the space and time complexity for TextRank the algorithm listed in this paper:
https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/papers/mihalcea.emnlp04.pdf

Since it is using PageRank whose complexity is:
O(n+m) ( n - number of nodes, m - number of arcs/edges)
and we run it over i iterations/until convergence the complexity for keyword extraction I believe it would be: O(i*(n+m))
and the space complexity would be O(V^2) using an adjacency matrix

While for sentence extraction I believe it would be the same thing.

I'm really not sure and any help would be great Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you repeat T times an algorithm (*inner*) with complexity O(n+m), or whatever other for that matter, it is correct to conclude that the new algorithm (*outer*) will have a complexity of O(T*(n+m)) provided:

1. The outer algorithm will only add a constant complexity every time it repeats the inner one.
2. Parameters n and m remain the same at every invocation of the inner algorithm.

In other words, the outer algorithm should prepare the inputs for the inner one in constant time, and the parameters of new inputs should remain well represented by n and m along the T iterations. Otherwise, if any of these two requirements fail to be proved, you should sum T times the complexities associated to the new parameters, say

```
O(n1 + m1) + ... + O(n_T + m_T)
```

and also take into account all the pre- and post-processing of the outer algorithm before and after using the inner.